# How to identify serial ports on new boards

Tags: linux, console, yocto

I'm porting a custom board based on I.MX233 using yocto and I'm wondering how you initially set the "console" kernel parameter?

Does the kernel assign serial devices based on first mentioned in device trees or by memory address?

And how do you know what the console name will be called? ex: ttyACM0, ttyS0, or even serial0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does the kernel assign serial devices based on first mentioned in device trees or by memory address?

That probably depends on the exact serial driver applicable to the hardware: if it has some kind of capacity for autoprobing, it may go by memory address (or whatever makes sense for the relevant autoprobe mechanism); otherwise it probably goes by device tree order.

> And how do you know what the console name will be called?

The default name will be dictated by the driver: if the hardware is based on the classic 8250 chip or its descendants/clones/compatibles, there is a strong precedent for using a `ttyS<N>` style name. Other drivers have their own naming schemes.

The `ttyACM<N>` names refers properly to USB Abstract Control Model driver for USB modems and ISDN adapters; a serial console with a built-in USB-serial adapter might present itself as an USB device compliant with that specification, to make it usable without a vendor-specific USB-serial adapter driver. But that would mean only that *the development workstation* you have connected the board to would see the USB serial console as `/dev/ttyACM0`; the board itself would see it as a normal serial port (for whatever is "a normal serial port" for the board's hardware architecture).

(It might be technically possible to build a USB interface device that presents an ACM interface at "both ends", however that would be disadvantageous as a console, as it requires the very complex USB subsystem to be started up before it could be used as a console. In general, you'd want the console device to be as simple as possible, so that it can be used as early in the boot process as possible, to enable easier debugging of any problems in initializing other hardware.)

On ARM architecture, the first serial port might be implemented using AMBA PrimeCell UART (also known as a PL011 UART), which would result in it being named `ttyAMA0` by the kernel driver.

---

You said "I'm porting a custom board based on I.MX233 using yocto". Does that mean you are working to get Linux running on a custom board type that has never before been run with Linux so far? If yes, then you'll need the hardware datasheet first: you'll need to write a device tree description of your custom hardware, or adapt an existing device tree description that is roughly similar. To do that, you'll need to know (or figure out) each hardware element on that board, and identify (or write, in the worst case) the appropriate Linux driver for each hardware element. You'll also need to find the base address of the hardware element (or whatever the driver needs to access the hardware element).

On PC hardware, there are ways for the system hardware/firmware to describe itself: the PCI/PCIe bus has a set of specified standard features that each PCI/PCIe device must have, designed to allow the automatic detection of any devices on the bus. The ACPI firmware will also supply a lot of system information about any PC hardware elements that are not on the PCI(e) bus, like serial ports, interrupt controllers and the like.

In some cases (e.g. if running on a very old system with a ISA bus with no ISAPnP), there may be no such hardware information available, but there are certain industry standard conventions, like having the first four 8250-compatible serial ports at I/O base addresses 0x3f8, 0x2f8, 0x3e8 and 0x2e8 in this order. Such conventions can allow the serial port driver to carefully probe some addresses and see if they respond like a UART, but this might cause the system to crash or hang if it has been configured in a non-conventional way, so in modern times such "autoprobing by blindly poking around" is considered an absolute last resort, to be avoided if at all possible.

On ARM hardware, **none of that may be available.** Since ARM hardware can vary so much (from something like a tiny Raspberry Pi Zero to a multi-processor server systems with a large number of PCIe slots), with different system bus architectures, trying to auto-probe things is going to be futile. Instead, when porting Linux to a new ARM system type, one of the first tasks is to write a device tree description that will tell the kernel what hardware elements the system has, where they can be found in the processor's address space, and which driver to use to control each of them.

**If** the system includes auto-probeable buses in its design, the device tree description would only have to describe the bus controllers for any such buses; the respective bus controller driver would then be able to auto-probe the rest of that bus.

For example, to identify serial ports on a Raspberry Pi, you would first look at the hardware documentation. Since RasPis have been developed specifically for use with Linux, the device tree descriptions already exist. But let's assume you're starting from scratch.

When porting Linux to a new ARM hardware platform, you would start with a hardware datasheet. [For RasPi, it would be this one.](https://datasheets.raspberrypi.com/bcm2835/bcm2835-peripherals.pdf)

On page 8, you'll find the first mention of a "mini UART", and the register addresses for it. If you are familiar with 8250-compatible UARTs, the register layout should look familiar to you; but nevertheless, you should continue to page 10, which describes the mini UART in more detail. It says:

> The implemented UART is not a 16650 compatible UART However as far as possible the first 8 control and status registers are laid out like a 16550 UART.

A 16550 is the successor for the original 8250 PC UART, and backwards compatible with it. Aha! It looks like this UART might be driveable with Linux's `CONFIG_SERIAL_8250` driver, i.e. the driver for PC-like serial ports. As a result, this UART would get a default name of `ttyS0`, since that's just what the Linuc PC serial port driver does.

On page 135 begins another description of an UART:

> The BCM2835 device has two UARTS. On mini UART and and PL011 UART. This section describes the PL011 UART. For details of the mini UART see 2.2 Mini UART.
>
> The PL011 UART is a Universal Asynchronous Receiver/Transmitter. This is the ARM UART (PL011) implementation.

So the mini UART was already described, and this description is for the other UART, which is known as "PL011 UART", or "ARM UART" i.e. this type of UART is somehow specific to ARM designs.

You could google for "PL011 UART Linux" or just search the [`drivers/tty/serial/Kconfig` file in a Linux source code package](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/tty/serial/Kconfig) for "PL011".

You would find that [Linux already has a driver for it, as a kernel configuration item `CONFIG_SERIAL_AMBA_PL011`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/9b57f458985742bd1c585f4c7f36d04634ce1143/drivers/tty/serial/Kconfig#L48). The next configuration option [`CONFIG_SERIAL_AMBA_PL011_CONSOLE`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/9b57f458985742bd1c585f4c7f36d04634ce1143/drivers/tty/serial/Kconfig#L59) allows the use of the PL011 UART as a system console, and the configuration option description tells you that the boot parameter for that is `console=ttyAMA0`, so now you'll know the default Linux name of this UART too, without [reading the source code of the actual UART driver.](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/9b57f458985742bd1c585f4c7f36d04634ce1143/drivers/tty/serial/amba-pl011.c#L2471)

Page 137 of the hardware datasheet identifies the base address of the PL011 UART, which you would need if you were writing a device tree description for a RasPi from scratch.

So, the *RasPi itself* would see its UARTs as `ttyS0` and `ttyAMA0`. But when you use an USB-to-serial (3.3v) cable to connect another computer to view RasPi's console output, plugging the serial side to the appropriate GPIO pins on the RasPi and the USB side to the other computer, the *other computer* would see the *USB-to-serial adapter* as `ttyACM0` or `ttyUSB0` (depending on the exact USB-to-serial adapter type) if that other computer is running Linux too.

If the USB-to-serial adapter chip was integrated to your custom board, to allow accessing its serial console with a simple USB cable, then the situation would be the same: the other computer used to view the console might see a `ttyACM0` device (because it's seeing an USB serial device that claims to support USB Abstract Control Model).

But the ARM device itself would use one of its own UARTs to connect to the serial side of the converter chip. The serial device name for the ARM device side is determined by the UART used at the ARM side, **not** by the serial-port side of the USB-to-serial converter chip.

Comment: So I should be able to read the device-trees, find the driver for the uart, then read the driver what what cDev it will be exposed to? If you have time could you walk me through finding what a uart would be called in a rpi? I know they're ttyACM... but it would help me understand more

Comment: Thank you that's exactly what I was looking for and gives me more info to work off of, thanks again for taking the time to explain it a bit more depth